# Why my Ajax POST not working on Mobile's browser?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple Ajax Call, it works perfectly in all of Windows's browser but neither in mobile's browser (Android and iOS), what did I do wrong?

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/System/Remove_Crons/' + '@Model.hexId'
 });

 [HttpPost]
 [Route("/System/Remove_Crons/{id}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Remove_Crons(string id)
 {
    await Models.Cron.RemoveAllAsync();

    return Json(true);
 }
```

Comment: Did you enabled  [`cross-origin requests-CORS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) on your `program.cs file`?  Did you checked which error you are getting?

Comment: This issue has been resolved by adding below, don't know why I must add it for Mobile to run correctly

            success: function (result)
            {
                .....
            }

Comment: Actually that's the `ajax convension`, the way you have shared, its fine however, this us the valid `ajax syntax` `$.ajax({type: "GET",url: 'http://localhost:5094/Todo/GetUserList',dataType: "json",contentType: "application/json",success: function (response) {}});`

Comment: You are welcome and glad to see you like it.